# Play Music Notes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, audio

I am developing a little free software project which is basically a music keyboard and score sheet editor.

My first step in this project is to play note and or conceive notes itself. I use timbre, which is a few documented http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js . My first function is to transform for example "C4" (do4 en français) in a audio sound from sine function.

But what I can't do for now is to play and stop notes. Play works for begin the sine wave but when I play a second note, the first note doesn't disappear so I got 2 sine  and then 3

My script
https://gitlab.com/mdahmen/Laterreestron.de/blob/master/pagesandapps/partgenie/js/lecture.js

http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js

The test page: http://laterreestron.de/pagesandapps/partgenie/index.php

Comment: do you have any code for what you are using already to generate the sound

Comment: It's in timbre.js library (unreadable for me)https://gitlab.com/mdahmen/Laterreestron.de/blob/master/pagesandapps/partgenie/js/libs/timbre/timbre.js

Answer (score 2):

I was able to play notes using `synth.noteOnWithFreq()` and then end them using `synth.noteOff()`  The code is based on the [Synthesizer](http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/PragmaSynth.html) example on the [timbre.js](http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/) project page. Make sure that you include the [keyboard.js](http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/src/extras/keyboard.js) library as show below.

**Run the code snippet, click on the input box, and type some letters**

```js
var synth = T("OscGen", {
  wave: "saw",
  mul: 0.25
}).play();

var keydict = T("ndict.key");

var midicps = T("midicps");

T("keyboard").on("keydown", function(e) {
  var midi = keydict.at(e.keyCode);
  if (midi) {
    var freq = midicps.at(midi);
    synth.noteOnWithFreq(freq, 100);
    window.key.innerHTML = midi;
    window.freq.innerHTML = freq.toFixed(2);
  }
}).on("keyup", function(e) {
  var midi = keydict.at(e.keyCode);
  if (midi) {
    synth.noteOff(midi, 100);
  }
}).start();
```

```html
<script src="http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/timbre.js"></script>
<script src="http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/src/extras/keyboard.js"></script>
<div>KeyCode: <span id="key"></span>, Freq: <span id="freq"></span></div>
<input id="keyboard" placeholder="Type some letters here">
```